# Exporting Settings and Build Configurations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build, settings

For context I am running Eclipse Kepler (version 4.3.2) for C++, though this question should apply to all other versions as well.

- I would like to capture all settings in each build configuration of a project in a way that is conducive to backing up and restoring.
- I would like other (junior) employees to be able to recreate my project from the source code and some settings file without manually inputting an abhorrent number of fields, flags, and commands.
- I may be moving on to another job, so I may not be able to help them troubleshoot a build process for software they've never touched.
- I want a way to facilitate the creation of new projects with the same build configurations

I am aware that under `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols`, it is possible to export and import settings. However, as far as I have seen, this only affects the settings under `Includes` and `Symbols` tabs, ignoring `Libraries`, `Library Paths`, and all the rest. Basically, I need to to capture `C/C++ General` and `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build` in their entirety.

Because of network restrictions, this absolutely must be done without third-party tools in my case. If there are good plugins or tools that would make this easier, though, go ahead and post them for the benefit of anyone reading this in the future!

Comment: You have a project which depends from some IDE settings? Can your project be build from the console?

Comment: Sure, it's possible (as it is with all IDEs that don't use their own compiler toolchain), but why is that relevant?

Comment: If you can build it w/o IDE then why do you want to persist IDE settings?

Comment: Because like every project of substantial size, I'm building it with the IDE, not with a console and text editor. That's not the question. Some of the reasons I want those settings to be portable are listed as bullet points in the question.

Comment: Ah, I think I see how we're miscommunicating - the settings I want to copy are the ones that controls how the project is built, not IDE settings like color schemes or IDE-specific preferences.

Comment: Let's imagine that your project is an open source project and someone wants to build it. So besides your project code they need to download specific IDE to just build it? Building should work from the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of useful findings:

The `.cproject` file in the Eclipse project's working directory contains all build settings for all build configurations. Replacing a project's `.cproject` will replace its settings. Note it's not as elegant as exporting/importing: **all settings are overwritten,** so it isn't a good approach if you want to import the settings into an existing project. It's useful for knowing you have the right build settings from scratch. though.

Alternatively, you can go to `Project -> Build Configurations -> Manage...` to manage configurations. It's possible to create a new build configuration by copying it from another project in your workspace.

Both are kind of clunky, but they may be enough to get the job done depending on the circumstance.